# Can't start the server with npm start in react JS

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

I'm trying to start a new react JS project and I have this error when I start the server (I don't modified the generated files)

```
Compiling...
/home/Dorph/comparateur-representant-web/comparator_web/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/Dorph/.#crux.c'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/home/Dorph/.#crux.c'
}
[Dorph@Host-002 comparator_web]$
```

I only do this command :

```
npx create-react-app hello-world ; cd hello-world ; npm start
```

If someone know how to fix this.

Comment: Please try using `&&` instead of `;`. Not entirely sure what's happening here, need additional logs to help further

Comment: At usual it change nothing, but I tried to make those commands one by one and I still have the same problem. What info do you need to help me ?

Comment: What OS is this on? If windows? Is WSL being used?

Comment: Hello, i'm using Fedora 32, and no, I'm not using WSL

Comment: What version of npm and node are you using? Can you please provide a screenshot of `nvm ls`, `node --version` and `npm --version`?